# Best practices for layouts with AppBar and Drawer: re-use vs "copy/paste"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm pretty new to Flutter and am looking for some "best practice" advice when it comes to building page layouts. I come from a Java background where I've always re-used as much as possible, but I'm not sure that's really the best approach here. I have several pages that will all have an Appbar but with their own actions. Each of these pages will share a common Drawer. Initially, I started going down the path of creating a common root page Widget where, when selecting an item in the drawer, the body of the common page changes, like this:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final BaseAuth auth;
  final Function onSignedOut;

  const HomePage({Key key, this.auth, this.onSignedOut}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final drawerItems = [
    new DrawerItem("Home", Icons.home),
    new DrawerItem("Pantry", Icons.store),
    new DrawerItem("Barcode Scanner", Icons.scanner)
  ];

  int _selectedDrawerIndex = 0;
  bool _isEmailVerified;

  _getDrawerItemWidget(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
      case 0:
        return new HomePageFragment();
      case 1:
        return new UserPantryFragment();
      case 2:
        return new BarcodeScannerFragment();
      default:
        return new Text("Error");
    }
  }

  _onSelectItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _selectedDrawerIndex = index);
    Navigator.of(context).pop(); // close the drawer
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var drawerOptions = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < drawerItems.length; i++) {
      var d = drawerItems[i];
      drawerOptions.add(new ListTile(
        leading: new Icon(d.icon),
        title: new Text(d.title),
        selected: i == _selectedDrawerIndex,
        onTap: () => _onSelectItem(i),
      ));
    }
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext =
        AuthenticationContext.of(context);
    return new FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
        future: authenticationContext.auth.getCurrentUser(),
        initialData: null,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> data) {
          var name = data.data != null ? data.data.displayName : "";
          var email = data.data != null ? data.data.email : " ";
          var photoUrl = data.data != null && data.data.photoUrl != null
              ? data.data.photoUrl
              : null;
          return new Scaffold(
              appBar: new AppBar(
                  title: new Text(drawerItems[_selectedDrawerIndex].title),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                    ),
                    // overflow menu
                    PopupMenuButton<String>(
//                      onSelected: _signOut,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return ['Logout'].map((String choice) {
                          return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                            value: choice,
                            child: Text(choice),
                          );
                        }).toList();
                      },
                    )
                  ]),
              drawer: new Drawer(
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                      accountName: Text(name != null ? name : ""),
                      accountEmail: Text(email),
                      currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
//                        backgroundImage: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
//                          placeholder: kTransparentImage,
//                          image: photoUrl != null ? photoUrl : "",
//                        ).image,
                        child: new Text(
                            photoUrl == null ? email[0].toUpperCase() : ""),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Column(children: drawerOptions)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              body: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex));
        });
  }
```

However, I'm now wondering if it would be better to just create the Scaffold from scratch in each screen and not try to use a shared root page as I'm running into issues with easily customizing the AppBar for each page. I was initially thinking I could just create some "buildAppBar" function on each of the page Widgets and have the root page use that, but that does not seem to be an easily achievable solution...at least not in an elegant way that I can find.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend `StatelessWidget` to add custom params to the class and return a customized `Scaffold` in the build method. Something along the lines of:

```dart
class MyScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget option1;
  final Widget option2;
  final Widget body;

  const MyScaffold({
    this.option1,
    this.option2,
    this.body,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: option1,
      drawer: option2,
      body: body,
    );
  }
}
```

You can also copy other properties from the `Scaffold` class and add them as members to `MyScaffold` (remember to initialize them in the constructor like the `body` and options params).

Another option to pass state (read: variables) down the widget tree is [`InheritedWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate widget for the drawer and just use in anywhere you need to.

Manage the Drawer State with a [Provider to Manage State](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

```
class DrawerStateInfo with ChangeNotifier {
  int _currentDrawer = 0;
  int get getCurrentDrawer => _currentDrawer;

  void setCurrentDrawer(int drawer) {
    _currentDrawer = drawer;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void increment() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Adding State Management to the Widget tree

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      providers: <SingleChildCloneableWidget>[
        ChangeNotifierProvider<DrawerStateInfo>(
            builder: (_) => DrawerStateInfo()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Creating The Drawer Widget for reuse in application

```
class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  MyDrawer(this.currentPage);

  final String currentPage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var currentDrawer = Provider.of<DrawerStateInfo>(context).getCurrentDrawer;
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              "Home",
              style: currentDrawer == 0
                  ? TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                  : TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            ),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              if (this.currentPage == "Home") return;

              Provider.of<DrawerStateInfo>(context).setCurrentDrawer(0);

              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                      MyHomePage(title: "Home")));
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              "About",
              style: currentDrawer == 1
                  ? TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                  : TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            ),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              if (this.currentPage == "About") return;

              Provider.of<DrawerStateInfo>(context).setCurrentDrawer(1);

              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => MyAboutPage()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Use of Drawer in one of your pages

```
class MyAboutPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAboutPageState createState() => _MyAboutPageState();
}

class _MyAboutPageState extends State<MyAboutPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('About Page'),
      ),
      drawer: MyDrawer("About"),
    );
  }
}
```